# Using a table from a library when namespaced

Tags: jtable, namespace

I'm using a library where i have some things like tables i use in different components i made.
Until now i could do this in a component model to use a table from my library:

```
class ItemModel extends AdminModel
{
    public function getTable($type = 'Item', $prefix = 'Mylib\\Library\\Table\\MyTable', $config = [])
    {
        return Table::getInstance($type, $prefix, $config);
    }
    ...
```

`Table::getInstance` is deprecated and when namespacing everything this no longer works as `createTable` works different:

```
class ItemModel extends AdminModel
{
    public function getTable($type = 'Item', $prefix = 'Mylib\\Library\\Table\\MyTable', $config = [])
    {
        return parent::getTable($type, $prefix, $config);
    }
    ...
```

This is also obsolete and i dont know how to replace it:

```
$item = Table::getInstance('Item', 'MyLib\\Library\\Table\\MyTable');
```

Is there a way to use a table directly from the library now?

Comment: You could create your own MVC Factory class which extends the Joomla one and then overrides createTable to use your library instead. Then you could just call getTable('item') in your model.

Answer (score 1):

You can try either of these method that I have used in components.

```
use Mylib\Library\Table\MyTable;
...
$this->db    = $this->db    ? :Factory::getContainer()->get('DatabaseDriver');
$item_table = new MyTable($this->db);
```

In MyTable I have this Class statement,

```
class MyTable extends Table
```

The `__construct` of the Table class requires you to pass in the database object.

You could also reduce it to two lines if you only have one reference to the table in your class.

```
$this->db    = $this->db    ? :Factory::getContainer()->get('DatabaseDriver');
$item_table = new Mylib\Library\Table\MyTable($this->db);
```

The getInstance() methods of a many number of Classes, being depreciated moving forward, works on the premise that if an instance of a requested Object already exists then use that object, if not then create a new instance of the object this and every subsequent request for the same object.

The getTable() and createTable() methods, ultimately they use `getMVCFactory()->createTable`, that you now see in Joomla 4 onwards simply creates an instance of the table and it is up to your code to manage whether you create a separate instance(s) or use an existing object if it already exists. I suspect this is why you mention getTable() doesn't work for you now.

I suspect you will need to have a different approach to the way you manage each call to each table in the Library if you are relying on getting the same instance of the object returned if it already exists. Something like calling  a 'getter' first that will return an existing object or create a new object calling a second method using the above example or a `createTable()` if the object doesn't exist.

I would also consider whether having Table classes in a Library is the best way to achieve what you are doing but that is beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Thanks. Does it make sence to start rewriting `Table::getInstance` at this point? Because i see in alle core Joomla 5 code `Table::getInstance` is still used. 
Maybe in near future there will be a leaner approach for this?